# Sending file contents in $_POST with PHP

Tags: php, file

I'm developing a PHP script to send the content of a file from one script to another. In PHP usually it's used the $_FILE array that contains any uploaded file submitted in a form. But I didn't needed a form so I came up with something a little different:

```
// pseudo function names ahead

$content = file_get_contents(FILE_TO_SEND);
send_file_with_curl(base64_encode(gzcompress($content)));
```

So this basically fetches the content of the file, then compresses it with gzip compression and then base64 encodes it. Then everything is sent with a cURL POST request. On the other side I get sent content base64 decode it, uncompress it and everything comes back untouched.

So my question is: Is there any downside in doing things this way? Are there any security or integrity concerns I might be overlooking?

I forgot to mention that I also send an md5 digest of the file to check if the transfer went ok. And files to be sent will never be more than 3Mb of size.

Thanks in advance for all your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found that the HTTP PUT method is nice for these kind of things.  You surely don't need to encode the file, and most likely should not bother with compression, etc...  There is no practical size limit to the following.  It is fast and uses a fixed amount of memory regardless of the file size.

---

This function will **HTTP PUT** a file from the local disk to a remote URL

```
//Specify the location of a tmp file
function PutFile($sName, $sFile)
{
    $URL = "http://MY-SERVER/PutFile.php?FileName=" . urlencode($sName);

    $FILE = fopen($sFile, 'rb');

    $curl = curl_init($URL);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INFILE, $FILE);

    ob_start();
        curl_exec($curl);
        $sReturn = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    curl_close($curl);

    fclose($FILE);

    return $sReturn;
}
```

On the remote end, this is **PutFile.php**

```
<?php

$Name = (get and **validate** file name from $_GET['FileName'];
$Path = /somewhere/to/put/the/file/ + $Name

set_time_limit(3);

$f1 = fopen('php://input', 'rb');
$f2 = fopen($Path, 'wb');

while($data = fread($f1, 4096))
{
    fwrite($f2, $data);
}

fclose($f1);
fclose($f2);

echo "Success\n";
```

If you do not want to write it to disk, but work with it in memory, you could simply use `file_get_contents('php://stdin')`.

Answer (score 1):

One possible disadvantage is that the base64 encoding will increase the overall transfer size significantly.  The compression will help, but base64 will add 33% overhead over the compressed file size.

Aside from that, I don't think there will be a big difference between the two methods.

Comment: As I noted to Frank, base64 adds exactly 33%. It encodes 3 bytes as 4. There is no guesswork here.

Answer (score 0):

That base64 encode is increasing your filesize 33% (per the comment below).  Also, you have to load the entire file into memory all at once.

If you took advantage of the normal method of file uploading, neither of these issues should be a concern.

Comment: base64 has a consistant overhead. Your file increases in size by 33%. It's as simple and predictable as that.  Saying it increases 'several fold' is misleading and incorrect.